# Espaçamento entre inputs quando campos estão ocultos

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando resolver o que considero um problema, tenho alguns campos que estão ocultos e somente são exibidos com alguns `radios` são selecionados e estão funcionando, mas o que gostaria de saber é se um modo de diminuir o espaçamento que existe hoje mesmo com os campos estando ocultos, sei que isso pode e deve ser algum erro que cometi, estou usando o `Bootstrap 3`.

Meu `Código`, não consegui inserir pela `Amostra de Código`, está ficando desconfigurado então para mostrar inseri pelo `Trecho de código`.

```html
<fieldset>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <label>Horário de trabalho: Segunda a Sexta *</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact[email]" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <label>Horário de trabalho: Sábado *</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact[email]" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <label>Horário de Intervalo *</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact[email]" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <label>Jornada de Trabalho *</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="JornadaTrabalho" value="1"><i></i> Turno 12 x 36</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="JornadaTrabalho" value="2"><i></i> Horas Extras - horário operacional - Sábado</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="JornadaTrabalho" value="3"><i></i> Outros Horários</label>          
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="MostraOutrosHorarios col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="display: none;">
            <label>Outros Horários *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <label>Trabalhou anteriormente na Empresa? *</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Historico" value="1"><i></i> Sim</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Historico" value="2"><i></i> Não</label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="MostraHistorico col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
            <label>Informar o Local *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
         <div class="MostraHistorico col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
            <label>Em que período? *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="MostraHistorico col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
            <label>Em que função? *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
         <div class="MostraHistorico col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
            <label>Motivo da saída? *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <label>Especificar motivo *</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="EspecificarMotivo" value="1"><i></i> Aumento de Efetivo</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="EspecificarMotivo" value="2"><i></i> Safra (Employer)</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="EspecificarMotivo" value="3"><i></i> Substituição</label>          
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="JustificarMotivo col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
            <label>Substituição à *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
         <div class="JustificarMotivo col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
            <label>Motivo da Substituição *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <label>Recebimento *</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Recebimento" value="1"><i></i> Cheque</label>
            <label class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="Recebimento" value="2"><i></i> Conta Bancária</label>        
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="MeioPagamento col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="display: none;">
            <label>Banco *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
         <div class="MeioPagamento col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="display: none;">
            <label>Agência *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
         <div class="MeioPagamento col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="display: none;">
            <label>Conta Corrente *</label>
            <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Uma imagem para ilustrar:

[image: Imagem do Formulário]

Os retângulos em vermelho mostram os espaçamentos que estou tendo, não consegui diminui-los e também não sei se tem como faze-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sugestão que te dou é usar a classe na `.row` externa que está com os elementos ocultos dentro, e não direto nos elementos que vc quer ocultar entende. Por exemplo como fiz com essa opção `.row.MostraOutrosHorarios` assim a .row inteira fica oculta e não da espaço branco no layout.

Repare que agora essa `.row` fica oculta e não ocupa espaço, assim como tudo que está dentro dela.

```css
.row.MostraOutrosHorarios  {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



    <div class="container">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                 <label>Horário de trabalho: Segunda a Sexta *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="contact[email]" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                 <label>Horário de trabalho: Sábado *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="contact[email]" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                 <label>Horário de Intervalo *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="contact[email]" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                 <label>Jornada de Trabalho *</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="JornadaTrabalho" value="1"><i></i> Turno 12 x 36</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="JornadaTrabalho" value="2"><i></i> Horas Extras - horário operacional - Sábado</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="JornadaTrabalho" value="3"><i></i> Outros Horários</label>          
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row MostraOutrosHorarios">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Outros Horários *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                 <label>Trabalhou anteriormente na Empresa? *</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="Historico" value="1"><i></i> Sim</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="Historico" value="2"><i></i> Não</label>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="MostraHistorico col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Informar o Local *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
              <div class="MostraHistorico col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Em que período? *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="MostraHistorico col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Em que função? *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
              <div class="MostraHistorico col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Motivo da saída? *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                 <label>Especificar motivo *</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="EspecificarMotivo" value="1"><i></i> Aumento de Efetivo</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="EspecificarMotivo" value="2"><i></i> Safra (Employer)</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="EspecificarMotivo" value="3"><i></i> Substituição</label>          
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="JustificarMotivo col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Substituição à *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
              <div class="JustificarMotivo col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Motivo da Substituição *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                 <label>Recebimento *</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="Recebimento" value="1"><i></i> Cheque</label>
                 <label class="radio">
                 <input type="radio" name="Recebimento" value="2"><i></i> Conta Bancária</label>        
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group">
              <div class="MeioPagamento col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Banco *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
              <div class="MeioPagamento col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Agência *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
              <div class="MeioPagamento col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="display: none;">
                 <label>Conta Corrente *</label>
                 <input type="text" name="OutrosHorarios" value="" class="form-control required">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: Olá @hugocsl, bom dia, muito obrigado mais uma vez, feliz Natal ai.

Comment: @adventistapr legal que resolveu ai, bom final de ano pra vc tb e boas festas!